# Wordpress Default Calender Changes

Tags: wordpress

in wordpress default calendar, need to have blue squares around all the Friday, Saturday and Sunday dates... how it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">

th[title="friday"],
th[title="saturday"],
th[title="sunday"]
{
    background: #09F;
}

</style>
```